# ECharts: Display Legend for Treemap?

Tags: legend, treemap, echarts

The treemap below has two levels. I want to display a legend for the top level nodes (Node A and Node B). With other types of charts I've used, the legend can be auto-generated or I can define it explicitly. With the treemap, it appears one is not auto-generated, and if I define one explicitly, it is never displayed.  Is it possible to display a legend for a treemap?

```
<style>
    #chart {
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
        right: 100px;
        bottom: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>


<div id="chart"></div>


<script src="http://echarts.baidu.com/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var options = {
        series: [{
            type: 'treemap',
            data: [{
                name: 'Node A',
                value: 20,
                children: [{
                    name: 'Node A1',
                    value: 12
                }, {
                    name: 'Node A2',
                    value: 8
                }]
            }, {
                name: 'Node B',
                value: 20,
                children: [{
                    name: 'Node B1',
                    value: 20
                }]
            }]
        }]
    };
    var chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("chart"));
    chart.setOption(options);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `legend` object of ECharts is constructed from the `series` object by default. This means that nested datas in `treemap` series aren't part of the legend. You need to make two entries in your `series`: one for `Node A`, one for `Node B`.

So you can first use the code below, and you'd see that you run into an UI-related issue.

```
{
  legend: {
    data: ['Node A', 'Node B'],
    top: 55,
    itemGap: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(243,243,243)',
    borderRadius: 5
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'treemap',
      name: 'Node A',
      data: [{
        name: 'Node A1',
        value: 12,
      }, {
        name: 'Node A2',
        value: 8,
      }]
    }, {
      type: 'treemap',
      name: 'Node B',
      data: [{
        name: 'Node B1',
        value: 20,
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

This code will run, but the legend <-> chart sync will not work properly since ECharts doesn't support multiselect mode legend for the `treemap` object (it's a bit technical). Basically, you can only use single-selection mode as of the current ECharts version.

To get rid of the weird UI issue, you will either have to remove the legends (since the `name` already describes each block in the map so you might not need any legend), or add the following line inside the `legend` object:

```
selectedMode: 'single'
```

This will allow you to have a properly working legend, but this will not allow you to display two series at the same time. At least, you will be able to switch between your entries in your `series` array.

Here is a demo screenshot on the official editor:
[Echarts demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Sext.jpg)

Comment: Thanks Ryo. I copied and pasted the code for your legend and all I got was a single bullet (due to borderRadius), I did not get entries labeled "Node A" and "Node B". Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome! Can you post a pastebin or anything that does the same job with the code that you have pasted? I just edited my answer and added a screenshot with the code I wrote here (it's properly rendered), take a look at it ; there might be other external causes to this issue.

Comment: OK, your little trick of pasting into the ECharts Example helped immensely. Thanks! So I was able to see that mine didn't work and your did, and found that the difference was in the series: each top level node is supposed to be a separate series. So I had the wrong series data structure. Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice to see it worked for you as well ! I always test in the ECharts example editor before using a new method or chart type, it really helps saving time. Happy coding :)